# storing the 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E to variable in java which is byte

Tags: java, macos, hex

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
        if (ni != null) {
            byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
            if (mac != null) {
                /*
                 * Extract each array of mac address and convert it to hexa with the
                 * following format 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E.
                 */
                for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                    System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
                }
            }
        }
```

**how to store outputs similar to this** `08-00-27-DC-4A-9E` to a variable in java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
    b.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");

String s = b.toString();
```

Comment: 08-
08-00-
08-00-27-
08-00-27-DC-
08-00-27-DC-4A-
08-00-27-DC-4A-9E

Comment: ... m able to fetch it to a string but i have shown u the output above.... i  just need 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E in the string s...

Answer (score 3):

To store that value to a variable instead of printing it, you can just declare a variable and change the last line to:

```
String s = "";
s += String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
```

Currently, you're formatting it into a string, but then printing it to the standard output instead of storing it.

Comment: mate output from the code is 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E... i need it to save to a variable ... its of byte[]... m asking u how to save it in java

Comment: dude - you have it in a variable of type byte [] it's called 'mac', please work out what you actually want

Comment: yup dude...i got to know... but wen i format it with System.out.format... its gives in this format 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E.. i need to save this particular output

Comment: bro - if you just want to reference the string that you'd otherwise print to the console, I've updated my answer.